# Apache Ivy settings task and ivysettings.xml file

Tags: java, ant, build, ivy

According to [this](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/use/settings.html) page, I need to declare an `<ivy:settings>` task inside my Ant build that helps Ant locate where the `ivysettings.xml` file is located. This setting file is where the definitions for all of my repositories can be found, as well as additional info.

What's confusing me is this: according to that page (link provided above), the following attributes are possible for the `<ivy:settings>` task:

- `id`
- `file`
- `url`
- `host`
- `realm`
- `username`
- `passwd`

The description for `url` is:

> url of the settings file to use

Implying that the `ivysettings.xml` file can actually be stored on a different machine, perhaps even *inside the repository itself?!?*.

But then the descriptions for the last for attributes (`host`, `realm`, `username`, `passwd`) are all of the variety:

> http authentication (host|realm|username|passwd)

**To me, these descriptions, combined with the one for `url`, indicate that the `host`, `realm`, `username` and `passwd` attributes are connection credentials for locating and retreiving the `ivysettings.xml` file; and that they are *not* connection credentials for connecting to a remote repository.**

This is further evidenced by the fact that Ivy allows you to define multiple repositories inside `ivysettings.xml`, including multiple `url-resolvers`, which could be different repositories located on different servers with different access credentials. Seeing that the `<ivy:settings>` task only allows you to specify one set of credentials with these attributes, again it seems to imply that these attributes are merely for finding and pulling down the `ivysettings.xml` file, and not for communicating with 1+ repos.

So, I ask:

- Are these 4 attributes for connecting to a `url` where `ivysettings.xml` lives, or are they for connecting to a remote repository that is defined inside `ivysettings.xml`?
- If the answer to the question above is that they are credentials for locating `ivysettings.xml` at a remote `url`, then where do I place the credentials for communicating with the web server where my actual repo lives (as the server where `ivysettings.xml` lives and the server where my repo lives may be two different machines)?
- Is my suspicion that you can store `ivysettings.xml` at a remote `url` (remote server) correct? If so, how do I tell Ivy to look at `Server A` with `Loging Credentials A` to find my `ivysettings.xml` file, but to find my repository at `Server B` with `Login Credentials B`?

**Please note**, some of you may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195393/where-do-you-put-ivysettings-xml) question and think that my question here is a duplicate of it. I argue that the referenced question above is simply the question "where do I put the `ivysettings.xml` file?" My question is *kind of* similar, however, at its core, its really about understanding the intention of the `<ivy:settings>` attributes, and what they're trying to find: the settings file, or the repo(s) defined inside the settings file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optional attributes on the [ivy settings task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/settings.html) are used when retrieving the settings file from a remote server. Within that [settings file](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings.html) you can use [credentials](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/credentials.html) tags to specify authentication credentials for remote repositories.

Examples:

- [http authentication between using ant/ivy retrieving dependency from nexus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001535/http-authentication-between-using-ant-ivy-retrieving-dependency-from-nexus/7490766#7490766)
- [Where do I put my credentials when using Ivy and a private company repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503630/where-do-i-put-my-credentials-when-using-ivy-and-a-private-company-repository/7505364#7505364)
- [Publish SNAPSHOT artifacts to Maven using IVY - what's the magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505062/publish-snapshot-artifacts-to-maven-using-ivy-whats-the-magic/8527089#8527089)