# Liferay 6.2 first application build failed- at build-common-ivy.xml:81: HTTP Authorization failure

Tags: java, sdk, liferay, portlet

I have installed the Liferay IDE 3.0 pluggin to Eclipse, Liferay portal 6.2 CE - GA6 server bundled with tomcat, liferay plugins SDK 6.2.

Trying to create my first portlet, but ending up with build failure, with the following error. Your Help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
Buildfile: E:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\build.xml

  [get] Getting: http:/mirrors.lax.liferay.com/cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-snapshots-ce/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  [get] To: C:\Users\shiva\.liferay\mirrors\cdn.repository.liferay.com\nexus\content\repositories\liferay-snapshots-ce\com\liferay\org.apache.ivy\2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT\org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  [get] Error getting http:/mirrors.lax.liferay.com/cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-snapshots-ce/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\shiva\.liferay\mirrors\cdn.repository.liferay.com\nexus\content\repositories\liferay-snapshots-ce\com\liferay\org.apache.ivy\2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT\org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  [get] Getting: http:/cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-snapshots-ce/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT/org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  [get] To: C:\Users\shiva\.liferay\mirrors\cdn.repository.liferay.com\nexus\content\repositories\liferay-snapshots-ce\com\liferay\org.apache.ivy\2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT\org.apache.ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar

BUILD FAILED
E:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:

E:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-plugins.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:

E:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:60: The following error occurred while executing this line:

E:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-ivy.xml:130: The following error occurred while executing this line:

E:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-ivy.xml:81: HTTP Authorization failure

Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 4):

In build.properties file just change that value of ivy.jar.url to:

ivy.jar.url=https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-snapshots/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/${ivy.version}/org.apache.ivy-${ivy.version}.jar

There are a problem in the repository!!

I faced the same issue and it works fine now

Comment: I think this link is not accessible now :(. I answer with a new URL which is not in Maven central repository. More chances to stay active (I hope !).

Answer (score 0):

In ivy-settings.xml check for the credentials tag and add if not existing

```
<credentials host="${nexus.host}" realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" username="${nexus.user}" passwd="${nexus.pass}" />
```

link: [http authentication between using ant/ivy retrieving dependency from nexus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001535/http-authentication-between-using-ant-ivy-retrieving-dependency-from-nexus)

Answer (score 0):

try this-
Copy the "ivy-2.4.0.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1-SNAPSHOT.jar" from fresh sdk and pest into .ivy folder